# tf is not recognized when using VSCode and TEE-CLC

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up TFS for the first time for VS Code on Windows. I'm getting troubles passing the final step. In the terminal I can use tf commands as long as I use the entire path:

```
C:\Users\...\TEE-CLC-14.111.1\tf.cmd workspaces
```

The last step for this set up is changing the user settings in VS Code:

```
"tfvc.location": "C:\\Users\\...\\TEE-CLC-14.111.1\\tf.cmd"
```

But when I try to use any tf commands, like tf workspaces, I get the following error:

```
'tf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have also tried using tf commands with tf.cmd and I get the same error message.

I've tried other versions of TEE-CLC with no luck (TEE-CLC-14.111.1, TEE-CLC-14.0.4, TEE-CLC-14.134.0). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the TEE-CLC path to **PATH Environment Variables** (user and system Path variable):

System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> edit the User **Path** and System **Path** variable -> add `;C:\Users\...\TEE-CLC-14.111.1` to the end of the varaible:

[image]